# Checking dates through script always coming up as zero

Tags: javascript, pipedream

I have written a script in Pipedream to get the dates I put in a certain column in my Google Sheets. I want to count them to be able to determine how many time a certain date appears in that column but I still get as count 0 and I do not know where it is going wrong. I tried the 5th of February because I have it appearing 5 times in that column just to test the code but for in the future it needs to check every day how many times the date of today appears.

```
export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    let count = 0;
    let dates = steps.get_values_in_range.$return_value;
    for (let date of dates) {
      if (date === "02-05-2023") {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return {
      count,
      event: steps.trigger.event,
      get_values_in_range: steps.get_values_in_range.$return_value,
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: What do you get if you log the `date` to the console? Is your `date` in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, or is it in another format?

Comment: I get it in mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(typeof date)` and simply `console.log(date)` as the first two lines after `for(let date of dates)`?

Comment: export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    let count = 0;
    for (const range of steps.get_values_in_range.$return_value) {
      if (range[0] === '02-05-2023') {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return {
      count,
      event: steps.trigger.event,
      get_values_in_range: steps.get_values_in_range.$return_value
    };
  }
});

Comment: i changed the code but it still appears as zero where do i need to put those 2 lines

Comment: Add them below `for (const range of steps.get_values_in_range.$return_value) {...`, and above  `if( range[0] === '02-05-2023') {...`. Since you have changed your code, you would now be using `console.log(typeof range[0])` and `console.log(range[0])`, instead of what I'd originally suggested.

Comment: at Object.run (file:///tmp/__pdg__/dist/code/81b6c86dc00c75efa27f51c70ff9d26902c14520dac0d4cbd94aeafcaafcbecf/component.mjs:6:17)
    at global.executeComponent (/var/task/launch_worker.js:139:53)
    at MessagePort.messageHandler (/var/task/launch_worker.js:598:28)

Comment: its giving me a refernce error

Comment: What do you get if you use `console.log(range)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(range)`? So, just the `range`, not `range[0]`.

Comment: What is in `dates` variable? Have you checked and make sure it contains an array?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change one line from your code.

```
  if (date[0] === "02-05-2023") {
    count++;
  }
```

Comment: import datetime

def handler(pd):
    count = 0
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    get_values_in_range = pd.steps["get_values_in_range"]["$return_value"]
    for range in get_values_in_range:
        if range[0] == today:
            count += 1
    return {
        "count": count,
        "event": pd.steps["trigger"]["event"],
        "get_values_in_range": get_values_in_range
    } this is my solution thanku guys i just wrote it in python

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def handler(pd):
    count = 0
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    get_values_in_range = pd.steps["get_values_in_range"]["$return_value"]
    for range in get_values_in_range:
        if range[0] == today:
            count += 1
    return {
        "count": count,
        "event": pd.steps["trigger"]["event"],
        "get_values_in_range": get_values_in_range
    }
```

Still thanks for the suggestions guys!